# How to change font size by javascript from css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some css.

```
.A B{
  font-size:34%
}
```

How can I change font-size from 34% to 30%? by javascript.
I tried some script like this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.card-full, .card-text')[0].style.fontSize='30%';
```

But, font size is changed weird.
And Chrome DevTools show Elements information like this.

```
.A B{
  font-size:34%
}
style attribute {
  ~~font-size:30%;~~
}
```

Oh... stackoverflow can't support strikethrough.

How can I change font size from css by javascript?

Comment: FYI, you can use `querySelector()` to select just the first match, instead of `querySelectorAll` and `[0]`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `!important` in the CSS? That will override the style of the element.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

It is strikethrough most likely because there're other css that has higher specificity.

The way you change the font-size using JS is correct. It would be helpful if you provide more details.

Edit: the arg inside querySelectorAll is probably not what u want as mentioned by @mplungjan.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.card-full, .card-text')[0].style.fontSize='30%';
```

The above will change the `card-full` element's font-size instead of the first `card-text`

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Inline styles normally have the highest precedence.

Comment: I apologised for that, rarely posted on SO, will take note on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what you want. Your spaces and commas and missing dots make it tricky to guess

Here is an example of what I think you meant - the 90% is for illustration

```js
document.querySelector('.card-full .card-text').style.fontSize='90%';
```

```css
.A .B{
  font-size:34%
}
```

```html
<div class="A card-full card-text">First card<p class="B card-text">Some text</p></div>
<div class="A card-full card-text">Second card<p class="B card-text">Some text</p></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('B')[0].style.fontSize = "30%";
```

if you need to '!imporant' option

```
document.getElementsByClassName('B')[0].setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 30% !important');
```

Comment: That's not the class they're trying to change.